# I just cannot fix the error in this code. Interpreter says, "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'"

Tags: python

```
def fun(n):
    while n>0:
        print n
        n=n-1

size = raw_input("Enter the no of terms")
fun(size)
```

Comment: Hint: what type is the return value of `raw_input`?

Answer (score 3):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string object. You need to convert it to number object using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) or [`float`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) to do numerical operations to it.

```
size = raw_input("Enter the no of terms")
size = int(size)  # <---
fun(size)
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [raw_input doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

Thus, you should convert `size` to `int`:

```
size = raw_input("Enter the no of terms")
fun(int(size))
```